# C# : Editing of footnotes in word 2007 using Microsoft.Office.Interop

Tags: c#, ms-word, footnotes

Is it possible to edit the footnotes within a document and place them directly on the reference number using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.

When i use the OpenXML the footnote reference is missing on some input files that is why im trying to make a program with the word interop.

---

what i mean in "directly place them in the reference number":

distributors exercise no control.2 (2 is a superscript)

2 See, e.g.: text(footnote)

output:

distributors exercise no control.See, e.g.: text.

its like replacing the number two with the footnote itself.

For the code :

This is only the one i've starting with in collecting all the footnotes

```
List<string> footNotes = new List<string>();
foreach (Footnote aNote in app.ActiveDocument.Footnotes)
            footNotes.Add(aNote.Range.Text);
```

Comment: I would say 'yes, it's possible'. But what do you mean with 'directly on the reference number'. Remember to add the code you have already tried if you expect any help (according to site FAQ).

Comment: sorry for that. Edited my post with an example of my question